# How to block internet access to specific application using Java?

Tags: java

I am creating app for blocking internet access for my browser. It should work more or less similarly to ColdTurkey but I have different mechanics in mind. I was thinking about maybe creating firewall exception and disable and enable that but I don't know about that. Also I am a beginner so I just want some light app, without complicated stuff, so I am not very keen on coding a plug-in as ColdTurkey did. Thanks for all suggestions.